# Once the popup closed, main page should be refreshed to load changed data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, modal-dialog

```
private void AddOrderItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "Orderdetails.aspx";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin('" + url + "')</script>");
}
```

I am using above code to open a popup window.

I have a page order.aspx from which I am opening another aspx page (Orderdetails.aspx). 
Orderdetails.aspx page opens as a popup. 
once user close the window(Orderdetails.aspx) , Orders.aspx page should post back and load newly added items.

How to catch the close event of the popup window?

Comment: you would need to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Put this script block in your child window:(Orderdetails.aspx)

```
<script>
        window.onunload = refreshParent;
        function refreshParent() {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Serhat I'll try this